# Forms create same time

Tags: delphi

I have two forms, and I want to firstly create main form and if the user click the button, send a variable and create second form.

But in my code, when I had started to application, it tried to create two form, but application crushes because second form has not a parameter yet.

main form call:

```
procedure TForm1.listItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  item: TListViewItem;
begin
  item:= AItem;
  zipId:= item.Text;
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

second form:

```
var
  Form2: TForm2;
  zipId: String;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses main;


procedure TForm2.ImageClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Image: TImage;
  i: Integer;
  begin
  Image:= Sender as TImage;
  if rects[Image.Tag-1].Fill.Color = TAlphaColorRec.Gray then
    begin
      rects[Image.Tag-1].Fill.Color:= TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
      rects[Image.Tag-1].Tag:= 1;
    end
  else
    begin
      rects[Image.Tag-1].Fill.Color:= TAlphaColorRec.Gray;
      rects[Image.Tag-1].Tag:= 0;
    end;

end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  path: String;
  stream: TBytesStream;
  Z: TZipFile;
  SR: TSearchRec;
  Dest: TStringList;
  i,j: Integer;
  getZipId: String;
begin
  url:= 'http://192.168.1.5:3030/api/db/';
  client.BaseURL:= url + 'Control';
  req.Method:= TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  req.AddParameter('getZip', Form1.zipId);
  req.Execute;
  path:= '/storage/emulated/0/';
  stream := TBytesStream.Create(DecodeBase64(res.Content));
  try    //ANDROID - System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim
    stream.SaveToFile(path + 'myfile.zip');
    Z := TZipFile.Create;
    try
        Z.Open(path + 'myfile.zip', zmRead);
        Z.ExtractAll(path + 'Library');

      finally
        Z.Free;
      end;
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
  if FindFirst(path + 'Library/'+'*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
  repeat
    if ExtractFileExt(SR.Name) = '.jpg' then
      Dest.Add(SR.Name);
  until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
  FindClose(SR);

  SetLength(imgs, Dest.Count);
  SetLength(rects, Dest.Count);

  for i := 0 to Dest.Count-1 do
  begin
    rects[i]:= TRectangle.Create(Form2);
    with rects[i] do begin
      Parent:= flow;
      Width:= 146;
      Height:= 112;
      Margins.Left:= 10;
      Margins.Right:=10;
      Margins.Top:= 5;
      Tag:= 0;
      Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Gray
    end;
    imgs[i]:= TImage.Create(Form2);
    with imgs[i] do begin
    Parent:= rects[i];
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile(path + 'Library/'+Dest[i]);
    Width:= 146;
    Height:= 112;
    Position.X:= 5;
    Position.Y:= 5;
    OnClick:= ImageClick;
    Tag:= i+1;
    end;
  end;
  if RemoveDir(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'Library') then
    ShowMessage('Silindi');
end;

end.
```

I am new on delphi, and I don't understand why when the application starts, it create two form.

Comment: Have a look in your .dpr file so see that both forms are created at startup. The IDE is leading you down a bad path here. By inviting you to create forms at startup and leave them in memory for the lifetime of your process. And by encouraging you to refer to the forms using public global variables. I personally don't do that. I get rid of the global variables, and create the forms when I need them.

Comment: Remove the second form from Project Options - Forms - Auto-create forms. Then you have to create the form manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In delphi in Project->View Source

You have something like this

```
program YourProgram;

uses
  Forms,
  uTForm1 in 'uTForm1.pas' {TForm1},
  uTForm2 in 'uTForm2.pas' {TForm2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Remove the line with `Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);`
So only the first form would be created at startup.

Then when you click the button to open the second form creat the second form.

```
procedure TForm1.listItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  item: TListViewItem;
  frm : TForm2;
begin
  item:= AItem;
  zipId:= item.Text;
  frm := TFrame2.Create(nil);
  frm .Show;
end;
```

Example : 
    // project source code 
    program Project1;

```
    uses
      Forms,
      Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
      Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

    {$R *.res}

    begin
      Application.Initialize;
      Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
      Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1); // creates only first form on start up
      Application.Run;
    end.


unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit2; 

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  frm : TForm2; // make an TForm2 object
begin
   frm := TForm2.Create(nil); // create the object 
   frm.Show; // show the object ( which in our case is a form )
end;

end.
```

Comment: There's no need to edit the project source to do this; you can use Project->Options->Forms, and just move the form from the Auto-create forms list to the Available forms list. It prevents errors when changing the project source, and means you can visually see the changes you're making (and undo them if you make a mistake).